# Making request to Google Drive from spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, google-cloud-platform, auth0

I have a react app front end that authenticates users using Auth0 Google plugin and when they are authenticated they are able to fetch private google images from google drive. The problem however arises when that app is being used on phone or in incognito, as third party cookies are blocked in these environments the requests to google drive is unauthenticated as the cookies are not attached in the request. So as a way around I am trying to get the hosting url of that google drive image by making an authenticated request from my server and then capturing the eventual redirected hosting url so that I can then send that to my front end and then fetch images using the src property in the img tag. The issue is that I am not sure how to authenticate my server and make  GET request to something like https://drive.google.com/file/d/someID/view?usp=sharing from my Spring boot server. I have tried using google credentials to get a token and making a request as shown belwo but that is not working either. Any ideas?

```
   @GetMapping("/getRedirect")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getData() {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(URI)
                .header(Bearer token here)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(String.class);
    }
```